# Overleaf: error in generating bibliography Undefined control sequence with \printbibliography

Tags: biblatex, overleaf

I am working fine on my Overleaf document until I inserted citation when the following error appears after using `\printbibliography` to generate reference list.:

```
Undefined control sequence.                      main.tex line 60
The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
namepartfamily ->Zim\x 
                        {fffd}\x {fffd}nyi
l.60 \end
         {document}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

This error disappears when `\printbibliography` is commented out, but then no reference list generated. I can confirm I added all required packages. See the document below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[top=25mm, bottom=25mm, left=25mm, right=25mm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\input{titlepage}
    %Table of content
    \tableofcontents



%Abasract page
\newpage
    \Large
     \begin{center}
     \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}
    \textbf{\textit Abstract} 
    \end{center}
    \hspace{10pt}

    %\normalsize
    This is a simple one-page abstract template. Please keep your abstract length at one page. The abstract should be in English.
    \newpage

%begin main document
\chapter{Introduction}

    \section{Statement of Problem}
    This is the beginning of the introduction section.
    %\subsection{Research Questions}
    \section{Motivation}

    \section{Research Objectives}

    \section{Pre-Thesis Structure}

%===CHAPTER TWO ===
\chapter{Fundamental Concepts}


%=== CHAPTER THREE ===
\chapter{State of the Art}
   \section{Transport}


%=== CHAPTER FOUR ===
\chapter{Material and Methods}


%=== CHAPTER FIVE ===
\chapter{Pilot Study}


%=== Reference Lists ====

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sounds like some character problem. Check in your .bib file and search for the text `Zim`, and check the character after it: you might need to re-type it carefully e.g.  `Zimányi` or `Zim\'{a}nyi` (or similar—Zimányi was the top search result I got when googling `Zim.?nyi` on Google Scholar)

Comment: Yes, seems as though `Zim?ny` is malformed. If LianTzeLim's guess that it should be `Zimányi` is correct, the issue is probably that the `á` is not encoded as Biber/`biblatex` expects. The easy solution would be that your `.bib` file is UTF-8, but LaTeX expects US-ASCII. Did you try adding `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` to your document? But maybe the `á` is malformed. Did you try deleting and re-writing the name? In any case you should clear the cache after you made the changes to avoid errors hanging about in temporary files: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Clearing_the_cache

Comment: Ah, you're right. adding the package `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.bib` file probably contains a line like

```
author  = {József Zimányi},
```

(all credits for the detective work of figuring out the name go to [LianTze Lim](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/226/liantze-lim) in [the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/504756/overleaf-error-in-generating-bibliography-undefined-control-sequence-with-prin#comment1275127_504756)). Quite likely your `.bib` file is encoded in UTF-8 or another non-ASCII encoding.

But with your preamble (and the outdated TeX system on Overleaf) LaTeX expects US-ASCII input only (a more current LaTeX will use UTF-8 as default encoding). The easiest way to get things to work again is to tell LaTeX you want to use UTF-8 with

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

You may have to clear the cache (see https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Clearing_the_cache) before you can recompile cleanly after that, but then you should get the desired output.